# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testTimeout')

Tags: jestjs

The jest 0.29 test case is to test component snapshot. Here is the error:

```
FAIL  src/components/post/piece/Itemdetail.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testTimeout')

      at _callCircusHook (node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:237:57)
```

The error is complaining about a jest -circus module. This is confusing as the error is about a jest module. here is the line of code being complained:

```
   const timeout = hook.timeout || (0, _state.getState)().testTimeout; //<<==run.js:237:57. _state is an import module.
```

How do I mock testTimeout for the jest-circus module to calm the error?

Answer (score 1):

By doing this:

```
global = {_smartContractObj:{wallet:"0x4k5jk43k6j5k4j5"}};
```

you are overriding global object. Instead it should be:-

```
global = {...global, _smartContractObj:{wallet:"0x4k5jk43k6j5k4j5"}};
OR
global._smartContractObj = {wallet:"0x4k5jk43k6j5k4j5"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line of code causing the error:

```
 global = {_smartContractObj:{wallet:"0x4k5jk43k6j5k4j5"}};
```

The error disappeared after the change (don't know why):

```
 global._smartContractObj = {wallet:"0x4k5jk43k6j5k4j5"};
```